# Как с помощью скрипта скопировать и применить к блоку более одного атрибута из ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть следующая конструкция:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.block').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    return false;
  })
});
```

```css
.block {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
  <p>Водитель "БелАЗа" смотрит на дорожные знаки чисто из любопытства.</p>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://yandex.ru">Текст ссылки </a></div>
<div class="block">
  <p>Неприятно наступать на грабли, еще неприятнее наступать на детские грабли.</p>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">Текст ссылки </a></div>
```

Скрипт в примере позволяет кликнуть по любой области блока с классам `block`  внутри которого расположена ссылка и соответственно перейти по ссылке. Как изменить скрипт, чтобы он не только копировал атрибут `href`, но также копировал и применял атрибут `target` чтобы при клике по блоку ссылка открывалась в новом окне.

**Благодарю за ответ!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, мы создаем новую ссылку, куда перетягиваем все атрибуты вашей и происходит автоматическое нажатие. Не важно что будет передано, все можно перехватить. Код представлен ниже:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.block').click(function() {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');  
        var target = $(this).find('a').attr('target');
if (target === undefined){
    target = '_self';
}
    a.target= target;
        a.click();
    return false;
  })
});
```

```css
.block {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
  <p>Водитель "БелАЗа" смотрит на дорожные знаки чисто из любопытства.</p>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://yandex.ru">Текст ссылки </a></div>
<div class="block">
  <p>Неприятно наступать на грабли, еще неприятнее наступать на детские грабли.</p>
  <a target="_self" href="https://google.com">Текст ссылки </a></div>
```

Только что проверил, если не указывать target, то тоже работает

```
<a href="https://google.com">Текст ссылки </a></div>
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо, учту на будущее.

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня почему-то данный скрипт не срабатывает в полном объеме. Блоку ссылка назначается, блок становится кликабельным и открывается ссылка которая указана внутри блока, но на атрибут `target` который указанный в ссылке не реагирует, ссылки открывается в этом же окне даже если указано `target="_blank"` Если у вас работает, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: @Slava я менял ваш код, проблем не возникло. Проверьте через F12 или режим разработчика Консоль, может там ошибки?

Comment: Ошибок в консоле нет, а версия  jQuery может быть причиной почему данный скрипт не срабатывает полностью? На сайте где пробую подключен  jQuery v1.12.4

Comment: @Slava проект был без использования сторонних библиотек. Может ссылка на ресурс будет, для которого делаете?

Comment: К сожалению нет онлайн, на локальном сервере пока развернут сайт

Comment: @Slava нашел проблему, мой косяк, тут операция присвоить 
`a.target= $(this).find('a').attr('target');`

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! Все заработало, блоки кликабельны, открывают ту ссылку что у них внутри и реагируют на значение атрибута  `target` в ссылке, в общем все что требовалось - работает! Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: А еще подскажите пожалуйста, для понимания, почему если у ссылки вообще не задан атрибут `target` ссылки все ровно открываются в новом окне? Какое значение в скрипте за это отвечает? И можно ли, сделать по умолчанию, что если вообще не задан атрибут, то открывать в родительском окне?

Comment: @Slava Поправил в ответе, можете смотреть.

Comment: Спасибо за рабочее решение! Сейчас все работает безупречно!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://yandex.ru">
  <div class="block">
    <p>Водитель "БелАЗа" смотрит на дорожные знаки чисто из любопытства.</p>
    Текст ссылки </div>
</a>
<a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">
  <div class="block">
    <p>Неприятно наступать на грабли, еще неприятнее наступать на детские грабли.</p>
    Текст ссылки </div>
</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.block').click(function() {
    window.open($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
    return false;
  })
});
```

```css
.block {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
  <p>Водитель "БелАЗа" смотрит на дорожные знаки чисто из любопытства.</p>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://yandex.ru">Текст ссылки </a></div>
<div class="block">
  <p>Неприятно наступать на грабли, еще неприятнее наступать на детские грабли.</p>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">Текст ссылки </a></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению, данный вариант не подходит. В вопросе условная конструкция. В верстку нет возможности вносить изменения, надо "налету" находить ссылку и делать кликабельным весь блок внутри которого данная ссылка, эту задачу отлично выполняет скрипт который в вопросе, но этот скрипт не может открывать ссылку в новом окне, если в ссылке которая внутри блока `block` есть соответствующий атрибут, именно с этим и прошу помочь

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас задача решена почти как и хотелось, но есть последний нюанс, сейчас все ссылки открываются в новом окне, вне зависимости от атрибута `target` подскажите, возможно ли  предварительно "опрашивать" ссылку  на наличие этого атрибута, если есть, то  открывать в новом, если нет то открывать ссылку как обычно

Comment: @Slava В Вашем коде уже присутствует получение значения атрибута ссылки. Получите другой атрибут (`target`) и делайте что угодно в зависимости от его значения.

Comment: В этом и проблема / суть вопроса, что у меня не получается, объединить в скрипте два атрибута и ссылку и как она должна открываться (

Comment: @Slava "у меня не получается" - мне через интернет плохо видно, как у Вас не получается

Comment: я поэтому и создал вопрос на stackoverflow. Первую часть моей задачи применить ссылку ко всему блоку внутри которого ссылка, делает скрипт из примера, но я не могу расширить функционал этого скрипта, чтобы помимо ссылки в расчет брался еще один атрибут. Тему вопроса постарался максимально понятно сформулировать, а также в комментариях дополнил, что именно не получается и попросил помощи, как применить к блоку и ссылку и атрибут `target` одновременно. Мои попытки добавить одновременно с самой ссылкой значение `target` приводят к тому что весь скрипт становится нерабочим

Comment: @Slava Конечно, конечно. Не хотите показывать Ваши попытки - не надо.

Comment: Еще один вопрос создать или как и где показать попытки?  Я реально не понимаю, я же и создал вопрос с просьбой помочь, после того как попробовал множество вариантов, но в силу слабых знаний они не к чему не привели

Comment: @Slava Под вопросом ссылка "править".

Comment: я не понимаю что нужно переформулировать в вопросе, посмотрите внимательно на заголовок и текст вопроса: ссылка копируется и применяется к блоку, а атрибут `target` не учитывается, вы подсказали в ответе как изменить скрипт и открывать все ссылки в новом окне, за это отдельное спасибо, но вот было бы еще решение как именно открывать ссылки в новом окне или нет в зависимости от атрибута  `target`, было бы супер , я к сожалению не могу это оформить в виде скрипта

Comment: @Slava Вы знаете, как получить значения атрибута `target` ссылки?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.